# When using the 2D tools is it possible to copy drawings into the next frame?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I am going to preface this by saying I am a total begginer so please excuse any mistakes. I recently downloaded blender to create 2D animation projects and have been enjoying getting to grips with it, however, I am looking for a way to copy and paste the entire frame into the next frame too. I want to do this to 'slide' my background images to create a panning camera effect wihtout having to redraw the entire background every frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In the dope sheet, just select the keyframe and duplicate it(shift-d) to wherever you want.

I would also like to mention that you don't have to slide your objects to pan the camera(assuming your using 2.80, which you definitely should, especially for 2D animation because there is major improvements.)  This is part of the beauty of using a 3d program for 2d animation.  you can animate the camera itself.

please comment if you need more information.